# clickhouse warning - Hoping that it will eventually appear as a result of a merge

Tags: clickhouse

After once restart of clickhouse-server

below waring appear 0.5s once at least.

```
2020.11.23 18:14:56.962144 [ 366 ] {} <Warning> timeseries.changchun (ReplicatedMergeTreePartCheckThread): Checking part 20201115_42618_42636_1
2020.11.23 18:14:56.964055 [ 366 ] {} <Warning> timeseries.changchun (ReplicatedMergeTreePartCheckThread): Checking if anyone has a part covering 20201115_42618_42636_1.
2020.11.23 18:14:56.970166 [ 366 ] {} <Warning> timeseries.changchun (ReplicatedMergeTreePartCheckThread): Found parts with the same min block and with the same max block as the missing part 20201115_42618_42636_1. Hoping that it will eventually appear as a result of a merge.
```

and DistributeSend is always bigger than 6.

I wonder there hava 6 parts  clickhouse-server want to send to other shard.

my clickhouse-server's version is 20.38.

how can i fix this warning?

one more thing my cluster have 3 shard and every shard have 1 replicate.

Answer (score 0):

DistributeSend is not related to the first issue.
Check system.distribution_queue

About the first issue. Check system.replication_queue
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/10368